# on-site interview: is it the earlier, the better?

Tags: interviewing, onsite

I did a phone interview and got the notice of an on-site interview at the same day today, they want me to be there early next week, which is pretty short notice.

If I can't be there, it will have to wait until after July 4th, which is two weeks away. And they are OK with that.

The position was just open for three weeks and they know I won't graduate until September.

The company is one of my top choices and this is my first time to look for a job. So I don't want to mess up my chance of getting an offer but I really don't know if there is a general wisdom of how to handle this situation. Any advice?

Edit:

I can't make it to early next week right now. I have to cancel a prior commitment for a meeting in order to be available.

I want to add that, another reason I'm inclined to go to this company later (after July 4th) is that I've already have another on-site interview scheduled for late next week. That company isn't so much my top choice so I want to get some on-site interview experience first though it and then be better prepared going into my top choice on-site interviews.

Comment: Did you talk back to them if it is possible to arrange an interview at a later date?

Comment: You say the appointment for next week is "pretty short notice", but you didn't say whether you can make it or not. If you *can* make it, what's the problem?

Comment: @Tichodroma yes, i did, they can arrange it to have it after 7/4.

Comment: @Brandin I have a meeting on Tuesday, so in reality, I can't make it without breaking a commitment

Comment: @olala In that case why not just say to the interviewer, "I have a prior commitment on Tuesday, so an appointment on that day would be too difficult for me to make." But seeing as they *already* offered you the 4 July alternative, you don't even need to say that. Just take the best option and commit to that. That is the best for everyone, no?

Comment: @Brandin i think the reason that they want me be there early next week is that this company wants to get ahead when they heard I have an on-site interview coming up next week. So it's best for me to go later and it shouldn't hurt the company anyway

Comment: @olala I don't see why you think that. From my perspective the company basically is saying "You can come in next week on Tuesday, *or* you can come in the week after." They're clearly giving you a choice. If the week after is better, take it.

Answer (score 9):

> they want me to be there early next week, which is pretty short
>   notice.
>
> The company is one of my top choices and this is my first time to look
>   for a job. So I don't want to mess up my chance of getting an offer
>   but I really don't know if there is a general wisdom of how to handle
>   this situation. Any advice?

**They want you there early next week - so be there early next week.**

There are no "tricks" to this. It's the same as any other request from a potential employer.

If you really want this job, you want to accommodate their requests if at all possible. So, even if it is inconvenient for you, try to show your eagerness to work at the company by making every effort to get to the interview in their time frame - early next week.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I should add that I have another on-site interview coming up later next week for a place that's not my top choice, so I want to go there first and get some experience for on-site interview before I go to this top choice. They are OK with putting it two weeks later. So I'm inclined to go this one later.

Answer (score 2):

You won't graduate until September, but you've already got yourself an interview - that's nice. If you can, go to the interview next week, else let them know you will be there July 4th. If you can't make it on either given dates, let them know either way.

Now, if you would to be hired, they will ask you when you can start. If you tell them you graduate in September, you could start 1-2 weeks (or whatever you prefer) after you've actually graduated. This way they've filled the position *and* you've got yourself a job. Ofcourse, things might not pan out that positively if they're looking for someone who can fill the position *right now*.

Comment: thanks for the answer. my feeling is that if they know i will graduate in September and still want to interview me, they are OK with putting this position back until September.

Answer (score 2):

Is earlier better? Yes. Often times you are not the only one being interviewed. If you can't make it next week they could give that interview slot to another candidate who could get the position. Ideally they will wait for you to interview as well, but if they have a big enough candidate pool they may not.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason that you can not be there in next week.If possible then you should reach there to grab opportunity. If you will ask them to setup interview according to your flexible time then it may be like they agree or disagree also its depends on your reason.

If for your it is not possible to reach there as per given time and they do now schedule interview as per your flexible time then also you do not need to be worry. In top companies this type of interview season comes frequently so you will have chance in future.

Comment: thanks for you answer! they can arrange the interview based on my schedule.

Comment: that's great....

Answer (score 1):

Later is fine especially if they don't mind waiting longer to accommodate you.  They won't make a decision until seeing all candidates.  You appearing busy (if you frame it as not any indication of your interest level) makes you look more busy and more valuable potentially.  Also a good trick to unleash for when you do schedule it - go for a Friday or at least Thursday.  Although anecdotal I have had superior interfaces with clients/potential employees end of week when they are in a better mood.  When they are happy they will attribute and spread some of this positive sentiment to you.  Best of luck to you!  If you don't get your first choice this time then get em next time